# NoneType object is not callable error on a full dictionary, stackoverflow fatal error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, spyder, stack-overflow

Im trying to make a web-scraping script. I'm bumping into an error and cant seem to figure out why.
I'm using spyder IDE, so all the variables are shown in variable explorer.
My code is as follows

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


root = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="


tickers = ['AMZN', 'GS']

news_tables = {}
for ticker in tickers:
    url = root + ticker
    req = Request(url=url, headers={'user-agent': 'dirty-30'})
    response = urlopen(req)
    #print(response)
    html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html')
   # print(html)
    news_table = html.find(id='news-table')
    news_tables[ticker] = news_table
    

amzn_data = news_tables['AMZN']
amzn_rows = amzn_data.findALL('tr')
print(news_tables)
```

I get back error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Exception in comms call get_value:

  File "C:\Users\austi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\commbase.py", line 347, in _handle_remote_call
    self._set_call_return_value(msg_dict, return_value)

  File "C:\Users\austi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\commbase.py", line 384, in _set_call_return_value
    self._send_message('remote_call_reply', content=content, data=data,

  File "C:\Users\austi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 109, in _send_message
    return super(FrontendComm, self)._send_message(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\austi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\commbase.py", line 247, in _send_message
    buffers = [cloudpickle.dumps(

  File "C:\Users\austi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)

  File "C:\Users\austi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py", line 609, in dump
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg) from e

_pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.
```

I tried adding

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000000)
```

When I attempt to open the
news_tables which is type=dict, I get a stack overflow message and the kernel restarts.
What am I missing here? I think the nontype error stems from the stack overflow breaking the variable so it just deletes the dict causing an empty dict aka nonetype...

Why am I getting a stack overflow? This shouldn't be that much data? One scrape of one page?
If my understanding of stack overflow is correct then all i can think of is there is somehow an infinite loop gathering the same data until i hit the pickling error ? I have several TB of mem on my system, have tons of RAM.

I'm perplexed any insights? I've restarted anaconda as a whole, my spyder is up to date.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what error you're actually getting.  Is it `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, or is it `_pickle.PicklingError`?

Comment: NonType object is not callable is the error.
But beneath it in the same terminal window it says pickling error, 
I pasted everything that comes up in the terminal window upon running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        allin = []
        for t in ['AMZN', 'GS']:
            params = {
                't': t
            }
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={'id': 'news-table'})[0]
            allin.append(df)
        df = pd.concat(allin, ignore_index=True)
        print(df)
        # df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


main('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx')
```

Output:

```
                     0                                                  1
0    Dec-10-22 01:30PM  Selling Your Home During the Holidays? 4 Moves...
1              12:21PM  15 Most Trusted Companies in the World Insider...
2              10:30AM  Target, Amazon and 4 More Retailers That Will ...
3              10:30AM  Opinion: These Will Be the 2 Largest Stocks by...
4              08:37AM       Better Buy: Microsoft vs. Amazon Motley Fool
..                 ...                                                ...
195            11:49AM  Goldman Sachs, Eager to Grow Cards Business, C...
196            10:53AM  Oil Slips as Swelling China Covid Cases Outwei...
197            08:42AM  Oil Dips Near $98 as Swelling China Covid Case...
198            08:41AM  Morgan Stanley funds have billions riding on a...
199            06:30AM  3 Goldman Sachs Mutual Funds Worth Betting On ...

[200 rows x 2 columns]
```

Or

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from pprint import pp

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        allin = {}
        for t in ['AMZN', 'GS']:
            params = {
                't': t
            }
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(
                'table', attrs={'id': 'news-table'}))
            allin[t] = soup
        pp(allin)


main('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx')
```

Comment: it's actually returning 2 df, but anyway let me combine that for you. hold on.

Comment: Do you know why its getting 103 per ticker? Can I adjust this? To be by date or something?
So I can get historical data for the last year or what have you?

Comment: @oz.vegas going from question to another isn't the way how SO is operating, please post another question within the community.

Comment: Fair enough, re-posted as a separate question haha. Thanks again.